# H2 Database - keep row number unchanged after updating row record

Tags: h2

So this is for H2 database. I have this issue that each time I update a record of row from a table, the updated row will automatically go to the end of the list. Is there a way to keep the row sequence unchanged even after updating? Thanks.

Comment: If you want an ordered result, use "order by".

Comment: Yes, I can. I was just wondering why the updated row will be inserted to the end of list if you select and return all rows, as well as that whether there is there a way to keep the updated row number unchanged.